# Rails 3 - CanCan to edit the current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When a user is looking at a user profile page, if the current user == the user profile I want to show an edit button...

So I have the following in the view:

```
    <% if can? :update, @user %>
        <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_registration_path %>
    <% end %>
```

And then in CanCan I have the following:

```
def initialize(user)
.
.
.
can :update, User do |user2|
  user2.try(:id) == user.id
end
```

But this is always equaling yes. not sure why? ideas

Answer (score 0):

I change the CanCan user var to current_user and that did it. I think the two users were confusing each other.